# Laravel Migrations: Error Exeption No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

A few days ago I installed Laravel and I have been working well, however this morning when trying to create a migration I get the following error:

This is the command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_zonas_municipios_table
```

This is the error I get:

```
[Error expetion]
include <C:\xampp....
......................>:failed to open 
stream:No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is that the full error? Checkout the Apache error log too.

Comment: I'm having this exact same error